# Missing raddb folder

Tags: freeradius, freeradius2, eap

Various tutorials on setting up a freeRADIUS server refers to the eap.conf file in the /etc/raddb folder. However when i install freeRADIUS on my ubuntu server, the eap.conf file are found in /etc/freeradius.

Is there a difference on the two folders: /etc/raddb and /etc/freeradius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the software has a default location for configuration files decided on by the developer which can be overridden at build time.

You, or typically a package maintainer and the packaging guidelines in use for that distribution, can decide on an alternate location.

The [official freeradius wiki](https://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Configuration-files)  refers to both:  `/etc/raddb` and `/etc/freeradius`

A location such as `/etc/raddb` might be chosen for backwards compatibility with a 
different Radius server.

Where `/etc/freeradius` is more obvious location and consistent location for a product called FreeRadius to store configuration files...

Comment: Only Debian/Ubuntu uses ``/etc/freeradius``, the official packages, Centos, RHEL and others use ``/etc/raddb``